# How do I plot confidence intervals in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, confidence-interval

I want to plot some confidence interval graphs in MATLAB but I don't have any idea at all how to do it. I have the data in a .xls file.

Can someone give me a hint, or does anyone know commands for plotting CIs?

Comment: The `ciplot` function is convenient. 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63314-ciplot-lower-upper-x-colour-alpha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by confidence intervals graph, but this is an example of how to plot a two-sided 95% CI of a normal distribution:

```
alpha = 0.05;          % significance level
mu = 10;               % mean
sigma = 2;             % std
cutoff1 = norminv(alpha, mu, sigma);
cutoff2 = norminv(1-alpha, mu, sigma);
x = [linspace(mu-4*sigma,cutoff1), ...
    linspace(cutoff1,cutoff2), ...
    linspace(cutoff2,mu+4*sigma)];
y = normpdf(x, mu, sigma);
plot(x,y)

xlo = [x(x<=cutoff1) cutoff1];
ylo = [y(x<=cutoff1) 0];
patch(xlo, ylo, 'b')

xhi = [cutoff2 x(x>=cutoff2)];
yhi = [0 y(x>=cutoff2)];
patch(xhi, yhi, 'b')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks Amro.......but i was wondering how can I have a graph like shown in the figure on the following link:

http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/bne/115/4/images/bne_115_4_764_fig5a.gif

I wanted to have the bars for variations in the graph i.e. if there is big variation in the graph the bar is longer and if the variation is lower then the graph should have smaller bars..

did u get what i mean to say?

looking forward....

Comment: I believe what you're asking for is the `errorbar` function: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/errorbar.html

Answer (score 9):

After reading numerous threads, here's my attempt.

[image]

```
% Get some random data
x       = linspace(0.3, pi-0.3, 10);
Data    = sin(x) + randn(1, 10)/10;
Data_sd = 0.1+randn(1,10)/30;

% prepare it for the fill function
x_ax    = 1:10;
X_plot  = [x_ax, fliplr(x_ax)];
Y_plot  = [Data-1.96.*Data_sd, fliplr(Data+1.96.*Data_sd)];

% plot a line + confidence bands
hold on 
plot(x_ax, Data, 'blue', 'LineWidth', 1.2)
fill(X_plot, Y_plot , 1,....
        'facecolor','blue', ...
        'edgecolor','none', ...
        'facealpha', 0.3);
hold off
```

Mostly based on this question: [Plotting with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214399/plotting-with-transparency)

Answer (score 4):

See e.g. these m-files on Matlab File Exchange:

- [plot confidence intervals](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13103-plot-confidence-intervals)
- [confplot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2683)

Comment: thanks rcs!! As i am a begineer in matlab can you tell me how can i run this m file? coz i can see an error? should i have to specify some input parameters or file to have a plot?

Comment: (+1), `ciplot` https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63314-ciplot-lower-upper-x-colour-alpha