# Fill bounded area under curve

Tags: matlab

Say I have a plot in Matlab:

```
x=-10:0.1:10;
plot(normpdf(x, 0, 3));
```

I would like to fill the area under the curve from `-4 < x < 4`. Similar question: If I for example wanted to fill the area to left of the curve from `0.04 < y < 0.1`?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6245626/201800).

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600260/how-do-i-plot-confidence-intervals-in-matlab/1603464#1603464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the matlab function [`area`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/area.html) which can help you solve your particular problem.

For example, filling the area under normpdf for -4 < x < 4

```
x=(-10:0.1:10);
xs=x(x>-4 & x<4);
figure;
hold on;
area(xs,normpdf(xs,0,3));
plot(x,normpdf(x,0,3));
```

For your second example however I do not know if this will work, but maybe a workaround is possible.

**UPDATE**: regarding your second question, I think you can achieve this with the Matlab function [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/fill.html). I did not test it but I am pretty sure it would work, if you are having difficulties implementing it do not hesitate to ask for help.

Answer (score 3):

Aabaz' answer is great for the general case, but if you specifically need to color the area under a normal pdf curve, there's actually a function in Statistics Toolbox that does precisely this: [normspec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/normspec.html).

```
p = normspec([1-3/128,Inf],1,2/128,'outside')
p =
    0.0668
```

[image: Normal PDF plot]