# Plotting with transparency

Tags: matlab

I have to plot two curves as below that overlap each other. How I can make the overlapping area transparent, in order that the lower curve is visible? In the overlapping area, I can currently only see the top curve.

```
x=0:0.01:2*pi;                  %#initialize x array
y1=sin(x);                      %#create first curve
y2=sin(x)+.5;                   %#create second curve
X=[x,fliplr(x)];                %#create continuous x value array for plotting
Y=[y1,fliplr(y2)];              %#create y values for out and then back
fill(X,Y,'b');                  %#plot filled area
%*****************
hold on
x=0:0.01:2*pi;                  %#initialize x array
y1=sin(2.*x);                   %#create first curve
y2=sin(2.*x)+.5;                %#create second curve
X=[x,fliplr(x)];                %#create continuous x value array for plotting
Y=[y1,fliplr(y2)];              %#create y values for out and then back
fill(X,Y,'b');                  %#plot filled area
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your last command `fill(X,Y,'b');` with:

```
h = fill(X,Y,'b');
```

to get a handle to the patch object it creates. Then type:

```
set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5)
```

[image]

Does that do what you need?