# Filling area between curves introduces lines back to beginning of curves

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to add a confidence interval to some noisy curves that I smoothed beforehand.  I used the method that is proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361932/3562088). In my case I implemented this like this:

```
tcd           % Cell array contains all the original data for multiple files
tcd_smooth    % Cell array contains the smoothed data for multiple files 

% Store all time-value pairs smaller than the original data in 
% lower_bound_times, lower_bound_values and all values larger than
% the original data in upper_bound_times, upper_bound_values
lower_bound_times = time{i_file}(tcd{i_file} < tcd_smooth{i_file});
upper_bound_times = time{i_file}(tcd{i_file} > tcd_smooth{i_file});
lower_bound_values = tcd{i_file}(tcd{i_file} < tcd_smooth{i_file});
upper_bound_values = tcd{i_file}(tcd{i_file} > tcd_smooth{i_file});

% Flip order of arrays to construct closed area that can be filled
X=[upper_bound_times; fliplr(lower_bound_times)];              
Y=[upper_bound_values; fliplr(lower_bound_values)];

fill(X, Y , 1,...
    'facecolor',colorOrder(mod(i_file-1,7)+1,:), ...
    'edgecolor',colorOrder(mod(i_file-1,7)+1,:), ...
    'facealpha', 0.2, ...
    'edgealpha', 0.2);
```

This snippet is executed for multiple files indicated by the index `i_files`. The confidence levels are filled nicely as shown in this zoomed plot of a single line:

[image: Zoomed in image of line with confidence interval]

However for some reason the end of all lines is connected with the beginned as shown in the following two plots:

[image: Full plot]

And the right hand end of plot looks like this:

[image: Right end zoomed in]

I can't wrap my hand around how to get rid of these returning filled areas.

Comment: It would seem you have your first data point on each line repeated as last entry again. That's what normally goes wrong when your last datapoint connects to the first one again.

Comment: Are you sure that `fliplr` flips your arrays along the right dimension? I imagine the goal is to have x values going from min to max then back to min again.

Comment: Using horizontal flip `fliplr` and vertical concatenation with `;` seems just wrong in `X=[upper_bound_times; fliplr(lower_bound_times)];`. Do you work with row or column vectors?

Comment: Hi @Brice and @Andras Deak! `lower_bound_times` and `lower_bound_values` are 4131x1 arrays and `upper_bound_times` and `upper_bound_values` are 4111x1 arrays. I will try to transpose and then use `,` instead of `;` immediately.

Comment: Yes this solved the problem! If you want you can write a short answer, that I can accept.

Comment: You can also use the vertical flip `flipud` instead of `fliplr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using horizontal flip `fliplr` and vertical concatenation with `;` seems just wrong in `X=[upper_bound_times; fliplr(lower_bound_times)];`

If upper_bound_times is a column vector, you should use an up-down flip in place of the left-right flip:

```
X=[upper_bound_times; flipud(lower_bound_times)]; %flip along first dimension
```

If it is a row vector, you should use horizontal concatenation with `,`:

```
X=[upper_bound_times, fliplr(lower_bound_times)]; %horzcat
```