# time series plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to get my time series plot in the form of second plot below. But I do not know how this bar chart in MATLAB can be obtained for a series time. Has anyone ever had such an experience to guide me? The first figure is an example of a time series plot that I want to plot in the form of the second plot.
It should be noted that the first image is with a simple plot command in MATLAB.
http://www.sidc.be/silso/datafiles#total
link address for data.i plot a daily data of sunspot number from the link that it's like the first curve here. now i want to have a curve like the second pic here for any time series data.
[image]

Comment: Those "bars" certainly represent a [confidence interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600260/how-do-i-plot-confidence-intervals-in-matlab), but without additional information we can not answer your question. Provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a stacked bar chart with two different sets of bars, then make the bottom bar white so it is invisible, then the top sets of bars will look like your above plot.  Here is some sample code and the plot it makes

```
bar_bottom = [0.5, 2, 1.5];
bar_height = [4, 5, 3];
x = 1:3;
h = bar(x, [bar_bottom; bar_height], 'stacked');
set(h(1),'EdgeColor', 'w', 'FaceColor', 'w') % set bottom bar to be white (invisible since background is white)
set(h(2),'FaceColor', 'c', 'EdgeColor', 'w', 'BarWidth', 1)
line(x, bar_bottom + 0.5 * bar_height, 'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]

Comment: here x is a data set? if i have a data of number how is it plot? in y axis i have numbers of sunspot and in x axis i have x=1:3432.